# min-width in media query is not working as it should be

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i tried to create a mobile first display but when i used media query with min-width(which is supposed to say : when device width is at least or equal to the specified width then apply the specified styles) but whole display for mobile also broke and it also got applied with the min-width styles.

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 700px){
    body{
        font-size: 1.8rem;
    }
    #hamburger{
        display: none;
    }
    nav ul{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }
}
```

In this first image i removed media query and this is what i get
[image: image when i remove media query]

In this second image i added media query which didn't work well
[image: second image]

Here's full code on codepen : https://codepen.io/Harsh_X/pen/mdVEORY

Comment: I just inspected your codepen and it is working

Comment: Do you have more than one media queries? If so, the ordering of these queries matter.

Comment: Can you confirm that the problem does indeed happen in the codepen? Your screenshots are of your localhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget to add the viewport meta tag. Without it devices with high pixel densities, like the iPhone 6 and up, will be rendered differently without accounting for the characteristics of the screen. Those devices tell you that they have a width of `375` pixels, but the actual resolution of the screen is the double of that: `750` pixels. That is because the device has a pixel ratio of `2` or higher. So all the numbers are doubled (or more) in reality.

So your media query sees that the device has `750` pixels in width, but they are rendered in `375` pixels, which is confusing, and therefor will trigger the media query at `700` pixels.

The meta tag here below corrects these values. A more detailed explanation can be found on [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag), which explains why a single pixel is *really* not a single pixel.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: While this is one probable cause, it doesn't address the OP's implication that the codepen doesn't behave as planned either. I mean, if you were correct, the codepen wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: Didn't realize the importance of these meta tags until now, it does work as expected after adding this meta tag